# Adobe Flash iPhone Game Development like Words/Hanging with Friends possible?

Tags: iphone, flash, adobe, flash-cs5

Adobe Flash CS 5 and 5.5 offers the ability to create applications for the iPhone. Would it be possible to create a multiplayer turn style game like the iPhone game Words/Hanging with Friends/Chess with friends?

If so anyone have any good places to start with. My only problem would be making multiplayer and turn style work. I am only curious as I am not up to coding par enough to do this with Objective C.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would be possible.  You could leverage a service like the Flash Collaboration Service (also known as LiveCycle Collaboration Service) to manage the state between games:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/services/collaboration.html

You would not be able to leverage GameCenter integration without a Native Extension.

Comment: Yeah I was aware of no GameCenter Support which is fine by me.